# Where can ros-jade packages for Ubuntu 14.04 trusty be found?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that ros-jade has been removed from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages and only ros-indigo is available.

If anyone knows of an archive with ros-jade for Ubuntu 14.04 trusty please pass it along.

When was ros-jade removed?  I feel like it was available in April of 2019.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327333/where-can-ros-jade-packages-for-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-be-found?/) by [nhonold](https://answers.ros.org/users/43697/nhonold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Jade has been EOL since May 2017 ([wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)), with the final package repository sync in September 2017 ([discourse announcement](https://discourse.ros.org/t/final-jade-sync-2017-09-03/2559)).

> When was ros-jade removed? I feel like it was available in April of 2019.

A breach of security of `build.ros.org` was detected around April/May ([discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/security-issue-on-ros-build-farm/9342)), as a precaution, all packages for supported distributions have been rebuilt and as part of the cleanup, all packages of no-longer supported ROS releases (which would include Jade) have been moved to the [snapshot repository](http://wiki.ros.org/SnapshotRepository) ([discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/security-issue-on-ros-build-farm/9342/8) by @nuclearsandwich ).

If you still want to/need to use ROS Jade, you'll have to install it from the snapshot repositories. The linked wiki page explains how to set that up.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nhonold](https://answers.ros.org/users/43697/nhonold/) on 2019-06-30**:
Thank you for the prompt reply.  This was exactly the information I was looking for.  Thanks again.